# Anonymizing column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so

```
IsCool IsTall IsHappy Target
0      1      0       1
1      1      0       0
0      1      0       0
1      0      1       1
```

I want to anonymize the column names except for target.
How can I do this?

Expected output:

```
col1   col2   col3    Target
0      1      0       1
1      1      0       0
0      1      0       0
1      0      1       1
```

**Source dataframe :**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"IsCool": [0, 1, 0, 1], 
                   "IsTall": [1, 1, 1, 0], 
                   "IsHappy": [0, 0, 0, 1], 
                   "Target": [1, 0, 0, 1]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proposed code :**

You can pass a dict to the `rename()` Pandas function with a dict like this in parameters :

`columns={'IsCool': 'col0', 'IsTall': 'col1', 'IsHappy': 'col2'}`

This dict is obtained by using of a zip function : `dict(zip(keys, values))`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"IsCool": [0, 1, 0, 1], 
                   "IsTall": [1, 1, 1, 0], 
                   "IsHappy": [0, 0, 0, 1], 
                   "Target": [1, 0, 0, 1]})


df = df.rename(columns = dict(zip(df.columns.drop('Target'), 
                                  ["col%s"%i for i in range(len(df.columns)-1)])))

print(df)
```

**Result :**

```
   col0  col1  col2  Target
0     0     1     0       1
1     1     1     0       0
2     0     1     0       0
3     1     0     1       1
```

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
cols = {
    col: f"col{i + 1}" if col != "Target" else col
    for i, col in enumerate(df.columns)
}

out = df.rename(columns=cols)
```

```
   col1  col2  col3  Target
0     0     1     0       1
1     1     1     0       0
2     0     1     0       0
3     1     0     1       1
```

You can also do it in place:

```
cols = [
    f"col{i + 1}" if col != "Target" else col
    for i, col in enumerate(df.columns)
]

df.columns = cols
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
# get all columns except excluded ones (here "Target")
cols = df.columns.difference(['Target'])
# give a new name 
names = 'col' + pd.Series(range(1, len(cols)+1), index=cols).astype(str)

out = df.rename(columns=names)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  Target
0     0     1     0       1
1     1     1     0       0
2     0     1     0       0
3     1     0     1       1
```